# cleanup() not working in useEffect() with Firebase Firestore onSnapshot

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have a React project that lists data from Firestore using the onSnapshot() listener.

Everything works fine, but when I navigate to a new page (which also has a list just like the one on the previous page, but with different data), the data from the previous list still shows on the new page. Only when I click on the page somewhere does the new data show.

Example:

`/home` shows a list of my posts.

`/friends` shows a list of my friends.

When I click on `/friends` from `/home`, I still see the list of my posts.

I have tried to unmount the listener like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {

      const posts = firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('posts')
        .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {

          var postsArray = [];

          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
              postsArray.push(doc.data());
          });

      setServiceProviderArray(postsArray);

      return function cleanup() {
          posts()
    };

  }, []);
```

But this does not do the trick.

I am using React-Router-Dom for the routing.

Is there anything I am missing here.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

This bit is a little confusing:

```
 return function cleanup() {
          posts()
    };
```

What are you expecting `cleanup()` to do?

In this instance the `return () => posts();` bit will unsubscribe your realtime listener when the component unmounts. That just means that if firestore database changes while the component is unmounted, you won't getan update with the new data. That's good, don't change what you are doing here. If you don't unsubscribe you will still get an update even when the component is not on the page and you will end up with a memory leak. More on detaching listeners here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener

It sounds like what you want to do is clear the data when you unmount. To do this you would have to write a function that clears it. The functional opposite of `setServiceProviderArray`. So something that clears the service provider array. Then you want to call then when you unmount. Maybe setServiceProviderArray([]); So...

```
return () => {
  posts()
  clearServiceproviderArray()
};
```

Maybe `setServiceProviderArray([])` will work. If that doesn't do the trick the share the code for `setServiceProviderArray()` and we can help you  create `clearServiceproviderArray()` by writing its functional opposite.

Comment: Seems like it works if I set a timeout of 500ms before calling setServiceProviderArray(posts).

Comment: That's because the new data is overwriting the old data. If that works for you that is fine but then I'm not sure what your question is. Also calling your cleanup is misleading then. You should call it unsubscribe or detach. You are not cleaning anything up unless you write a cleanup function.

Answer (score 3):

Would be nice to get a Sandbox example or something to see how the implementation that you have done looks like. Since there's a lot of ways to do it.

what you can do is have a hook with a listener to launch `useEffect` every time you want data by new criteria.

```
const [query, setQuery] = React.useState("posts");


  useEffect(() => {

      const posts = firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection(query)
        .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {

          var postsArray = [];

          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
              postsArray.push(doc.data());
          });

      setServiceProviderArray(postsArray);

      return posts.unsubscribe();
    });

  }, [query]);
```

This way every time you use setQuery() your postsArray will be repopulated.